# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLabel has been deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to run the following piece of code but it gives me an error  **RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLabel has been deleted**. I'm unable to figure out why is it happening.

I searched other answers but they all said it has something to do with  **setCentralWidget**. But I'm not using it. So, why's the error occuring in my code?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import cv2
import imutils
import os


class CameraWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Independent camera feed
    Uses threading to grab IP camera frames in the background

    @param width - Width of the video frame
    @param height - Height of the video frame
    @param stream_link - IP/RTSP/Webcam link
    @param aspect_ratio - Whether to maintain frame aspect ratio or force into fraame
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, stream_link=0, btn_text=None, aspect_ratio=False, parent=None, deque_size=1):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize deque used to store frames read from the stream
        self.deque = deque(maxlen=deque_size)

        self.screen_width = width - 8  
        self.screen_height = height - 8
        self.maintain_aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio

        self.camera_stream_link = stream_link

        # Flag to check if camera is valid/working
        self.online = False
        self.capture = None

        self.video_display_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.video_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.video_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(btn_text)
        self.video_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(128, 159, 255)")
        self.video_btn.clicked.connect(self.message)
        self.video_frame = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.video_layout.addWidget(self.video_btn)
        self.video_layout.addWidget(self.video_frame)
        self.video_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.video_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.video_display_frame.setLayout(self.video_layout)

        self.load_network_stream()

        # Start background frame grabbing
        self.get_frame_thread = Thread(target=self.get_frame, args=())
        self.get_frame_thread.daemon = True
        self.get_frame_thread.start()

        # Periodically set video frame to display
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.set_frame)
        self.timer.start(.5)

        print('Started camera: {}'.format(self.camera_stream_link))

    def load_network_stream(self):
        """Verifies stream link and open new stream if valid"""

        def load_network_stream_thread():
            if self.verify_network_stream(self.camera_stream_link):
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_stream_link)
                self.online = True
        self.load_stream_thread = Thread(target=load_network_stream_thread, args=())
        self.load_stream_thread.daemon = True
        self.load_stream_thread.start()

    def verify_network_stream(self, link):
        """Attempts to receive a frame from given link"""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False
        cap.release()
        return True

    def get_frame(self):
        """Reads frame, resizes, and converts image to pixmap"""

        while True:
            try:
                if self.capture.isOpened() and self.online:
                    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
                    status, frame = self.capture.read()
                    if status:
                        self.deque.append(frame)
                    else:
                        self.capture.release()
                        self.online = False
                else:
                    # Attempt to reconnect
                    print('attempting to reconnect', self.camera_stream_link)
                    self.load_network_stream()
                    self.spin(2)
                self.spin(.001)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def spin(self, seconds):
        """Pause for set amount of seconds, replaces time.sleep so program doesnt stall"""

        time_end = time.time() + seconds
        while time.time() < time_end:
            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def set_frame(self):
        """Sets pixmap image to video frame"""

        if not self.online:
            self.spin(1)
            return

        if self.deque and self.online:
            # Grab latest frame
            frame = self.deque[-1]

            # Keep frame aspect ratio
            if self.maintain_aspect_ratio:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=self.screen_width)
            # Force resize
            else:
                self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))

            # Convert to pixmap and set to video frame
            self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, self.frame.shape[1], self.frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
            self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
            self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)                  ### error comes in this line.

    def get_video_frame(self):
        return self.video_frame

    def get_video_display_frame(self):
        return self.video_display_frame

    def message(self):
        self.zone_config = ZoneConfig(self.camera_stream_link) 
        self.zone_config.show()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("VIDS")
        titleBar_logo = os.path.join(dir, 'logos/logo.png')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(titleBar_logo))
        self.showMaximized()

        self.screen_width = self.width()
        self.screen_height = self.height()

        # Layouts & frames
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.top_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.top_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")
        self.mid_frame = QtGui.QFrame()   
        self.mid_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")
        self.btm_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.btm_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")

        self.layout.addWidget(self.top_frame, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mid_frame, 20)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btm_frame, 1)

        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Top frame
        label = QtGui.QLabel('VIDS Dashboard')
        label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 20))
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.top_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.top_layout.addWidget(label)
        self.top_frame.setLayout(self.top_layout)

        # Middle frame
        self.mid_layout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()

        # Create camera widgets
        print('Creating Camera Widgets...')
        self.one = CameraWidget(int(self.screen_width), int(self.screen_height), camera1, 'Camera 1')
        self.two = CameraWidget(int(self.screen_width), int(self.screen_height), camera2, 'Camera 2')

        cam_widget = Cam2(self.one, self.two, self)
        self.mid_layout.addWidget(cam_widget)
        self.mid_layout.setCurrentWidget(cam_widget)
        self.mid_frame.setLayout(self.mid_layout)  

        # Bottom frame
        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton('1 Cam')
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.button1)
        btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton('2 Cams')
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.button2)

        self.btm_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btm_layout.addStretch()
        self.btm_layout.addWidget(btn1)
        self.btm_layout.addWidget(btn2)
        self.btm_frame.setLayout(self.btm_layout)
        self.show()

    def button1(self):
        cam1_widget = Cam1(self.one, self)
        self.mid_layout.addWidget(cam1_widget)
        self.mid_layout.setCurrentWidget(cam1_widget)

    def button2(self):
        cam2_widget = Cam2(self.one, self.two, self)
        self.mid_layout.addWidget(cam2_widget)
        self.mid_layout.setCurrentWidget(cam2_widget)


class Cam1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, one, parent=None):
        super(Cam1, self).__init__(parent)

        # Add widgets to layout
        print('Adding widgets to layout...')
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(one.get_video_display_frame(),0,0,1,1)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Cam2(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, one, two, parent=None):
        super(Cam2, self).__init__(parent)

        # Add widgets to layout
        print('Adding widgets to layout...')
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(one.get_video_display_frame(),0,0,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(two.get_video_display_frame(),0,1,1,1)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class ZoneConfig(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, camera, parent=None):
        super(ZoneConfig, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI(camera)

    def initUI(self, camera):

        self.setWindowTitle("VIDS")
        titleBar_logo = os.path.join(dir, 'logos/logo.png')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(titleBar_logo))
        self.showMaximized()

        self.screen_width = self.width()
        self.screen_height = self.height()
        
        self.camera = camera

        # Layouts & frames
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.top_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.top_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")
        self.mid_frame = QtGui.QFrame()   
        # self.mid_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")
        self.btm_frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.btm_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")

        self.layout.addWidget(self.top_frame, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mid_frame, 20)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btm_frame, 1)

        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)        

        # Top frame
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('VIDS - Zone Configuration')
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 20))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.top_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.top_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.top_frame.setLayout(self.top_layout)

        # Middle frame
        self.mid_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mid_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")

        # Create camera widgets
        print('Creating Camera Widgets...')
        self.cam = CameraWidget(self.screen_width, self.screen_height, self.camera)

        self.mid_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mid_layout.addWidget(self.cam.get_video_frame())
        self.mid_frame.setLayout(self.mid_layout)

        self.mid_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.mid_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mid_frame.setLayout(self.mid_layout)   
        
        # Bottom frame
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Dashboard')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.goMainWindow)

        self.btm_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btm_layout.addStretch()
        self.btm_layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.btm_frame.setLayout(self.btm_layout)

    def goMainWindow(self):
        self.close()


dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
window = None
camera1 = 'streams/Fog.avi'
camera2 = 'streams/Overspeed.avi'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))                            # applies to entire window 
    window = MainWindow()
    # window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am using python 3, pyqt 4 and windows 10.

Comment: I cannot test your code, but I'd start by avoiding using `global` like that anyway, especially to create new instances (which is probably the reason of your problem): a `window` object already exists, you should not create new ones.

Comment: @musicamante, I have updated my code by removing ```global``` but the problem stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in the handling of threads it does not synchronize the elimination of the objects correctly, so a possible solution is to use sip to verify if the object was eliminated or not:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sip
```

```
# ...
self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
if not sip.isdeleted(self.video_frame):
    self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)
```